# Android Tabs showing under bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to setup tabs for my android application using expo go and react-native.

This is how it shows up, the bottom white part is the tab bar.
[image: This is how it shows up, the bottom white part is the tab bar.]

I know this because when i give the tab bar a `bottom: 50` style i get this
[image: good image]

This is an issue for android devices, because i do not want to hide the bottom navigation bar. but at the same time i want the tabs to be above it. I can programatically get the device type, but i cant find a way to get the height of the bottom navigation bar. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is called window insets on Android, apparently it's called `useSafeAreaInsets` in React Native.

Comment: @Philio it seems there is whitespace that is the same height as the tab bar that stays at the bottom of the screen when i move the tab bar, any idea how to removr that?

Comment: I looked into insets, and unfortunately bottom is 0

Comment: Sorry Peter, it was just a guess, I have no knowledge of React or React Native. When building Android native UIs there are various simple ways to get the window insets which are automatically calculated. Searching Google though it looks like there are a few libraries that might help, such as https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context

Comment: Thank you i appreciate the help! i figured it out, i just had to wrap the Tabs in a SafeAreaView